# Hide init struct in C and use init function

Tags: c, function, struct, malloc

there is a struct typedef which I am writing to init some functionality(Embedded microcontroller programming)

however if this struct is init badly can crash the whole thing down, so I decided to write a function to init the struct and malloc the memory then send back the pointer to the user in function return. like this code below:

```
//this is just a demonstration of what i want not the code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
}mystr;

mystr * init_str(int a, int b)
{
    mystr * strinit = (mystr *)malloc(sizeof(mystr));
    //for example no more than 10 is acceptable !!
    if(a<10)
        strinit->a=a;
    else
        strinit->a=10;
        
    if(b<10)
        strinit->b=b;
    else
        strinit->b=10;

    return strinit;
}

 void deinit_str (mystr * str)
 {
    free(str);
    str=NULL;
 }
    
int main()
{
    mystr * strinit = init_str(5, 15);
    printf("numbers are = a: %d , b: %d \n",strinit->a,strinit->b);
    deinit_str(strinit);
}
```

here out put is 5 and 10

however the struct is still visible to the user and they can just ignore using the init function and go straight for the struct and use that which kills the whole porpuse of this method, like this code:

```
//this is just a demostration of what i want not the code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
}mystr;

mystr * init_str(int a, int b)
{
    mystr * strinit = (mystr *)malloc(sizeof(mystr));
    //for example no more than 10 is acceptable !!
    if(a<10)
        strinit->a=a;
    else
        strinit->a=10;
        
    if(b<10)
        strinit->b=b;
    else
        strinit->b=10;

    return strinit;
}

 void deinit_str (mystr * str)
 {
    free(str);
    str=NULL;
 }
    
int main()
{
    //IGNORE CREATE AND WRITE WHAT EVER
    mystr strinit={
        .a=5555,
        .b=6969,
    };
    //THE NUMBERS ARE HIGHER THAN 10 AND NOT acceptable
    printf("numbers are = a: %d , b: %d \n",strinit.a,strinit.b);
}
```

here out put is 5555and 6969 which is wrong
how can i restricts the use of struct and just allow creation with init function

if there is no way to do this in C, can I do something like this in C++ ?

Comment: There are hundreds of other ways to break a program without using that struct at all. Document how it is meant to be used and if the documentation is ignored they get what they get.

Comment: Programmers are a breed of people who often circumvent limitations, no matter how much effort and thoughts you put into avoid this they will find a way around. Instead just document it and leave it at that, plus have some asserts sprinkled around in the code to check the values so that they dont crash your code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no I meant C++

Comment: @RetiredNinja you are right! nevertheless, i am trying to minimize the possibility

Comment: @AndersK I did put a lot of code to check in the function which uses this struct, preventing the code from going wrong is more desirable though, the documentation has the warning

Comment: @S2G There is a bright side to trying to make it hard for someone to use incorrectly. When they do, and if you find out about it, the code and their explanation for why they did it that way will probably be entertaining to read. :) I've seen some amazing workarounds in the past.

Comment: In c++ you'd make the members private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `struct` into an opaque type and keep the implementation details hidden inside your `.c` file. Doing this clearly shows the *intent* that the data that is connected to this type is not something one should mess with in any other way than by using the functions *you* provide.

Example:

Public header file:

```c
typedef struct {
    void *ptr;
} Handle;

Handle init_str(int a, int b);
void deinit_str (Handle h);
```

Internal implementation in the `.c` file:

```c
typedef struct { // never exposed in a public header file
    int a;
    int b;
} mystr;

Handle init_str(int a, int b) {
    mystr *ms = malloc(sizeof *ms);
    *ms = (mystr){.a = a < 10 ? a : 10,
                  .b = b < 10 ? b : 10};
    return (Handle){.ptr = ms};
}

void deinit_str (Handle h) {
    free(h.ptr);
}
```

In the documentation, you'd only mention that the functions in your library return or take a `Handle`.

Of course, someone with knowledge about the internal implementation details can still work around this, but it takes a little more effort and someone doing that certainly don't do it by mistake and should be prepared for surprises, should you change the internal represantation in the next release of the library.

Comment: Thank you! i have never used this before , i am going to test this and then give feedback

Comment: @S2G You're welcome! I've used this myself, not primarilly to hide implementation details from the user but, to be able to provide C interfaces to C++ libraries. The C compiler only see the opaque `Handle`-like types and the C++ compiler sees both and compiles the internals. It has worked out nicely.

Comment: Why so complicatd. Simply return void *pointer

Comment: @0___________ It's to add some type safety. When doing this myself in a library, I found  it helped the users to get it right when there are many `Handle`-like types. It's nicer to get an _"incompatible type for argument"_ compilation error than a crash if one makes a mistake :-)